# How to create a file that has no name but only extension in PHP?

Tags: php, fopen

I'm trying to create a file using PHP but the problem is that the needed file has no name but only an extension. How can I do it?
The present code just doesn't make the file but it also doesn't give me an error.

```
fopen( '.extension', 'w' )or die( 'ERROR MESSAGE' );
```

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't create the file?

Comment: No, you only think. I can understand where the confusion comes from though, since you can't actually *see* the file.

Comment: Ignacio and Phillip are just saying that the file is created, but is hidden.

Comment: sorry mates but answering my question with a question wasn't that helpful... thanks @Philipp !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files with only an extension and no name are treated as hidden in unix. To list them, you might call `ls -la` inside the terminal.

So the code you posted should just work fine. Note: you should always close the file opend with `fopen`!

```
$f = fopen( '.extension', 'w' );
if ($f) {
    fclose($f);
}
```

Comment: thanks... maybe it was too many hours coding, my hidden files were set to NOT DISPLAY on my FTP software